# how to cache table data in java

Tags: java, database

we a facility in .net called recordset which stores the table data in the cache and can be used as table to fetch data from it which makes data retrival fast

do we have anything like that in java, if so how to cache them, how to retrive them,  what is the access time, would it be faster than fetching from database,
can anybody help implementing it....

Answer (score 1):

To cache already fetched data you might be interested in [Ehcache](http://ehcache.org/documentation/getting_started.html)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the [java.sql](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/package-summary.html) package Specially the [ResultSet](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html), [Rowset](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sql/RowSet.html) classes